# How to write all lines that match to a file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to go over every file in a directory and if there is a match (specific IP in the file content), to write those matches into a new file in another directory. And do this for every file in the directory.
So far I have this, but it writes only one line in the new file. Could you guys help?

```
import os, re

wanted = ['10.10.10.10']
dir_list = os.listdir('D:\\path\\07')

for i in dir_list:
    n = open('D:\\path\\07\\'+i,'r')
    m=n.readlines()
    for line in m:
        if  any(wanted_word in line for wanted_word in wanted):
            with open('Z:\\PYTHON\\Filtered-'+i,'w') as filtered_log:
                filtered_log.write(line)
```

I have tried this one as well - nothing.. no error, even no result here.

```
import re, os

regex = "(.*)10.10.10.10(.*)"

dir_list = os.listdir('D:\\path\\07')

for i in dir_list:
    n = open('D:\\path\\07\\'+i,'r')
    for line in n:
        if re.match(regex, line):
            with open('Z:\\PYTHON\\Filtered_'+i,'w') as filtered_log:
                filtered_log.write(lines)
```

Comment: `<offtopic>` Did you forget to escape the dots?

Comment: I would just like to point out that by opening a file as `w` you are truncating whatever file used to be there, make sure to open it so that you're able to append

Comment: The dots are not a problem, they are written as intended. The problem indeed was in the file mode. Everything works now. Cheers user2599709

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is a special character in regular expressions, so you need to make sure you escape it:

```
>>> import re
>>> e = r'10\.10\.10\.10'
>>> s = "There are some IP addresses like 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.1, but the one I want is 10.10.10.10 and nothing else"
>>> s2 = "I only contain 192.168.0.1"
>>> re.search(e, s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f501fb771d0>
>>> re.search(e, s2)
```

What is happening with your code is that everytime you match a line, you open the file again in write mode, which deletes the contents of your file; the effective result is only the last line in written.

You need to make sure you open the file only once for writing, and then close it when you have filtered all the files in your target directory:

```
import os
import re

e = r'10\.10\.10\.10'

base_directory = r'D:/path/07'
base_dir_out = r'Z:/Python/'

for f in os.listdir(base_directory):
    with open(os.path.join(base_directory, f), 'r') as in_file,
         open(os.path.join(base_dir_out, 'Filtered-{}'.format(f), 'w') as out:
          for line in in_file:
              if re.search(e, line):
                  out.write(line)
```

Note the following:

1. You can use `/` even in Windows.
2. You should always use `os.path.join` when combining file paths.

Answer (score 1):

You're opening your file as `w`, which will truncate the previous file, that's why you only see one line in the new file.

```
wanted = ['10.10.10.10']
dir_list = os.listdir('D:\\path\\07')

for i in dir_list:
    n = open('D:\\path\\07\\'+i,'r')
    m=n.readlines()
    n.close()
    for line in m:
        if  any(wanted_word in line for wanted_word in wanted):
            tempFile = 'Z:\\PYTHON\\Filtered-' + i
            if exists(tempFile):
                with open('Z:\\PYTHON\\Filtered-'+i,'a') as filtered_log:
                    filtered_log.write(line)
            else:
                with open('Z:\\PYTHON\\Filtered-'+i,'w') as filtered_log:
                    filtered_log.write(line)
```